# Does C++ guarantee the minimum number of std::placeholders::_N?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming, language-lawyer

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders):

> The `std::placeholders` namespace contains the placeholder objects `[_1, . . . _N]` where `N` is an implementation defined *maximum number*.

I just wonder:

**Does C++ guarantee the *minimum number* of** `std::placeholders::_N`**?**

Comment: Why nothing there? ... https://eel.is/c++draft/func.bind.place#lib:placeholders

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no guaranteed minimum number of placeholders. [**[func.bind.place]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/func.bind.place) explicitly calls out the number as an "implementation-defined number of placeholders."

However, it is likely that you will have access to 10 different placeholders, as [**[implimits]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/implimits#2) says:

> The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.

With [**[implimits] 2.40**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/implimits#2.40) saying:

> Number of placeholders ([func.bind.place]) [10].